# Create an entry type on plugin install

Tags: plugin-development

When a user installs my plugin, I would like the plugin to create an entry type on install. First of all, is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the direction of where I would find documentation on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to add an entry type to a pre-existing section, or you want to create a new element type? (see here https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/element-types.html#getting-started)

Comment: Thanks @user3788089--I think Element Types will work!